# Generic traits not visible in external module

Tags: rust

I have next code:

```
pub trait Osm<T> {
    fn get_points(&self) -> Vec<Point<T>>;
}

#[deriving(Show, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct Point<T> {
    pub lat: T,
    pub lon: T,
}

#[deriving(Show, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct Node<T> {
    pub point: Point<T>,
}

impl<T: Clone> Osm<T> for Node<T> {
    fn get_points(&self) -> Vec<Point<T>> {
        return vec![self.point.clone()];
    }
}
```

When I put this code to main and call:

```
let b = Node { point: Point { lat: 10i64, lon: 12i64 }};
println!("{}", b.get_points());
```

all work fine.

But when I put it to another module get next error:

```
/prj/src/main.rs:64:22: 64:34 error: type `osm::test::Node<i64>` does not implement any method in scope named `get_points`
/prj/src/main.rs:64     println!("{}", b.get_points());
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I little bit confused why it not work, probably it's make private method because for main all work fine, but when I try use `pub` keywords it show `unnecessary visibility qualifier` build error. So can I use generic traits for external module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use a trait method in a different module, you need to `use` the trait first.

So `use osm::test::Osm;` should work. This is the only case where a `use` statement imports functionality instead of just making an identifier available.

Also, methods don't need explicit `pub`s for `pub trait`s since exporting the trait exports the methods.